# Does Qt 5.13.0 really take up 20.49 GB?

Tags: qt5, installation

I downloaded the offline installer for Qt5 from here. The developer and designer tools are automatically selected for installation, but Qt 5.13.0 is not. I would imagine I need to install that, but the size is 20.49 GB. Am I supposed to install this?

Comment: Online installer works well. Offline installer might make sense for archival/restore purposes, but you could also just back up the installation after using the online installer.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a specific reason you want to use the offline installer? It is recommended to use the online installers, which give you much more control over which modules and kits you want to install :

> We recommend you use the Qt Online Installer for first time
>   installations and the Qt Maintenance Tool for changes to a current
>   install.

Your link is not shown in your question. On [the official Qt website](https://www.qt.io/offline-installers)
They say that the size should be less than 3.3 GB. So if you realy want to use the offline installer, you should take that road.